# Javascript - d3 Stacked bar graph for data fetched from server

Tags: javascript, d3.js, stacked-chart

I am a newbie to JS. I am trying to create a stacked bar graph. I have been following this example - [Create a stacked graph](http://codepen.io/gordonwoodhull/pen/EgNvNr?editors=1010). When I try to import data from server, the rectangles (or the stacked graphs) don't show up. There should have been 130 bars in the chart. Only the labels on x-axis are visible. Here is the .js file -

```
queue()
.defer(d3.json, "/data2")
.await(makeCharts);

function makeCharts(error, recordsJson) {

var data = recordsJson;
var dateForm = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d["timestamp"] = dateForm.parse(d["timestamp"]);
    d["timestamp"].setHours(0,0,0);
});

var ndx = crossfilter(data);

var XDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d["timestamp"];});


var YDimension = XDimension.group().reduce(
function reduceAdd(p, d) {
  p[d["running_slot"]] = (p[d["running_slot"]]|| 0) + 1;
  return p;
},
function reduceRemove(p, d) {
  p[d["running_slot"]] = (p[d["running_slot"]]|| 0)-1;
  return p;
},
function reduceInitial() {
  return {};})


dc.barChart("#Chart")
.width(30080).height(400)
.dimension(XDimension)
.group(YDimension,"6-10",function(d) {return d.value["6-10"];})
.stack(YDimension,"10-14",function(d) {return d.value["10-14"];})
.stack(YDimension,"14-18",function(d) {return d.value["14-18"];})
.stack(YDimension,"18-22",function(d) {return d.value["18-22"];})
.stack(YDimension,"22-2",function(d) {return d.value["22-2"];})
.stack(YDimension,"2-6",function(d) {return d.value["2-6"];})    
.transitionDuration(1500)
.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(XDimension)) 
.renderlet(function (chart) {

//Check if labels exist
var gLabels = chart.select(".labels");
if (gLabels.empty()){
    gLabels = chart.select(".chart-body").append('g').classed('labels', true);
}

var gLabelsData = gLabels.selectAll("text").data(chart.selectAll(".bar")[0]);

gLabelsData.exit().remove(); //Remove unused elements

gLabelsData.enter().append("text") //Add new elements

gLabelsData
.attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
.attr('fill', 'white')
.text(function(d){
    text_object =  d3.select(d).data()[0].data.value
    console.log(text_object)
    return text_object
})
.attr('x', function(d){ 
    return +d.getAttribute('x') + (d.getAttribute('width')/2); 
})
.attr('y', function(d){ return +d.getAttribute('y') + 15; })


})


dc.renderAll();

};
```

This is how the sample date looks like -

```
[{"running_slot":"10-14","timestamp":"2016-07-29 07:01:37"}, 
{"running_slot":"10-14","timestamp":"2016-07-31 07:56:05"}, 
{"running_slot":"10-14","timestamp":"2016-08-01 01:44:41"},
{"running_slot":"10-14","timestamp":"2016-07-28 05:45:51"}, 
{"running_slot":"10-14","timestamp":"2016-08-02 06:22:10"},
{"running_slot":"10-14","timestamp":"2016-07-28 05:05:10"},
{"running_slot":"10-14","timestamp":"2016-08-05 06:39:19"},
{"running_slot":"2-6","timestamp":"2016-06-04 03:44:40"},
{"running_slot":"10-14","timestamp":"2016-06-04 03:48:29"},
{"running_slot":"2-6","timestamp":"2016-06-04 03:48:54"},
{"running_slot":"2-6","timestamp":"2016-06-04 03:50:09"},
{"running_slot":"6-10","timestamp":"2016-06-04 06:14:34"}];
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/sajeetharan/pen/LRqLZr

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think the problem is I need to show 130 such bars. It works for lesser no. of stacked bars though. So somewhere the dimensions (x-axis) are not correct. So, the bars are not visible.

Comment: Ok but I think you can put a range

Comment: Oh. Can you tell me how do we put such range?